# Copy/Paste with keyboard in rxvt

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, rxvt

I know that I can copy and paste text in `rxvt` by using the middle mouse button, but I was wondering if there was a way to define keyboard-shortcuts in the `.Xdefaults` for copy and pasting text.

Moreover it would be really awesome if it would be possible to select the text with the keyboard as well.

**EDIT:**

Trying to use urxvt-perls does not seem to work (maybe because of the zsh-VI-bindings?). When I try running the script from the command line I also get the following errors:

```
% perl keyboard-select 
Bareword "urxvt::ControlMask" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at keyboard-select line 137.
Bareword "urxvt::ControlMask" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at keyboard-select line 151.
Execution of keyboard-select aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Unfortunately I know nothing about a perl and have no idea if this is anyhow related to it not working in urxvt itself.**strong text**

Comment: For pasting, there is the default shift+insert. This is a fairly universal method of pasting (in that different OSes and applications support it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [urxvt-perls](https://github.com/muennich/urxvt-perls) to enable keyboards shortcuts for copy and paste in urxvt.

Place the required scripts in `/usr/lib/urxvt/perl/` and add these lines to your `.X{resources,defaults}`:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: ...,keyboard-select
URxvt.keysym.M-Escape: perl:keyboard-select:activate
```

Comment: Is there any way to see if the modules are loaded and do something? Following the github instructions does not work - or could it be that it does not work with the ZSH-vi-bindings?

Comment: It should work once you have reloaded your resources file: `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` It _may_ be an issue with the bindings otherwise...